# Using Django with $.ajax()

Tags: python, ajax, json, django

I am trying to do something simple with Django and Ajax.

My goal is to make a kind of lobby website, where each client knows the names of everybody currently in the lobby.

The way I'm doing it (bear with me even if it's the most awful method you've ever heard of) is to have the client send a message every second that says "I'm still here!". If the server doesn't here from a client for five seconds, that client is removed from the list of people in the lobby. I have this working.

What I can't figure out is how to send the list of players names that I have in by Django view back to the client. I've been trying to use JsonResponse and then receiving that in the success function of the `$.ajax()` call, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my `$.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: apiUpdateUrl,
        method: "post",
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: Cookies.get("csrftoken")
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.player_list)
        }
});
```

Here is my Django view:

```
def update(request):
    if Player.objects.filter(nickname=request.user.username).count() == 0:
        player = Player(nickname=request.user.username, time_joined=datetime.datetime.now())
        player.save()
    else:
        player = Player.objects.get(nickname=request.user.username)
        player.save()
    curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    for player in Player.objects.all():
        if (curr_time - player.last_update).total_seconds() >= 5:
            Player.objects.filter(pk=player.pk).delete()

    player_list = [p.nickname for p in Player.objects.all()]
    print(player_list)
    return JsonResponse({"player_list": player_list})
```

Comment: Post your code, please! :)

Comment: @kittykittybangbang I posted it

Comment: What do you get in `data`? Try `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Nevermind, it works!

Answer (score -1):

Not a solution but a few optimizations that I can recommend-

1) **No need for post request :** you can make a get ajax call since you are not sending any data.

2) **you can reduce code in your view like this :**

```
def update(request):
    player = Player.objects.get_or_create(defaults={'time_joined': datetime.datetime.now()}, nickname=request.user.username)[0]
    curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    Player.objects.filter(last_update__lte=curr_time-datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)).delete()

    player_list = Player.objects.all().values_list('nickname', flat=True)
    print(player_list)
    return JsonResponse({"player_list": player_list})
```

Comment: Shouldn't the optimization go as a comment rather than an answer. I won't downvote it ... :)